# Looking for a software solution which acts like a hardware KVM

Tags: synergy, kvm-switch

I've seen programs like Synergy before which allow a keyboard and mouse to be used across multiple systems.  Unfortunately Synergy treats both systems like they are the same thing (when you move the mouse too far to the right it jumps to the other computer, along with keyboard input).

I only have 1 monitor so what I need to do here is have a quick way to view my other desktop that is easy to manage.  Remote desktop is difficult because you have to take it out of fullscreen, then minimize it and then re-maximize it when you want to use it again.  If there were a single button I could hit to switch to the other computer that would be optimal.

Both computers are on the same lan.

Comment: I've usually used Remote Desktop in a window for the other machine.

Comment: This has several other disadvantages such as multiple clicks to switch between systems.
1. Undo fullscreen
2. minimize
and to restore it takes a few clicks too.

I'm looking for a single key press kind of deal if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading your question as trying to implement a hardware-based optimal solution in a software-based manner.

I would still look at the RDC solution, and to achieve your goal of a single-button toggle, to go for a hotkey scripting program like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), and map the entire maximize/minimize flow to a relatively unused button (F12, Pause/Break) to your keyboard to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Once I'm in the RDC if I hit the button again it wouldn't exit.  Instead that button press would be sent to the remote machine.  The way VMWare does it with their vSphere client is what I'm looking for.  Except, this is not a virtual machine, it's a HUGE desktop tower.  We're going in the right direction.

Comment: Under RDC, there's an option in "Local Resources" for "Apply Windows key combinations" - maybe you can set it to "On this computer", and map a corresponding Win+Pause to do the toggle? Given it is a 2-button press...

Comment: that technically would work but then there's the drawback of not being able to type any key combination.  I do programming all day and CTRL+F2 is a common break shortcut and I really need that when a program is locked up.  I certainly appreciate the thought though.

Comment: You might want to do a combination of these RDC LOCAL-ONLY keys from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwilbur/archive/2007/02/24/remote-desktop-shortcut-keys.aspx, and also the toggle AutoHotkey macro. That's convoluted, but it should work